# Configure ldap client to not search local system accounts in ldap server

Tags: ldap, authentication, users, local

We've an ldap server and clients configured to authenticate users against it. Everything is working fine apart that I saw in the ldap server logs that says that the clients also contact the ldap server to authenticate users as root, apache etc, how to disable that ?

Thanks

Comment: Which method are you using for your LDAP lookups? `sssd`, `nslcd`...?

Comment: I'm using nslcd. I found the nss_initgroups_ignoreusers parameter and added it to /etc/pam_ldap.conf and /etc/openldap/ldap.conf  (for root, apache, postfix etc) and restarted nslcd,  It works for the ubuntu clients but is completely ignored by the centos ones (Centos6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, finally resolved the problem with Centos clients by adding the parameter nss_initgroups_ignoreusers in /etc/nslcd.conf, not in /etc/pam_ldap.conf nor in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf. 
Not sure why but that was the only case that worked.